# Bind Data in a sheet view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I debugged the code and apparently on the first tap the selectedNew variable comes nil but when I close the sheetView and tap on another card the selectedNew is populated with the correct information.

```
 ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                        HStack(spacing: 20) {
                            ForEach(vm.latestNews.prefix(3)){card in
                                NewsCardView(title: card.attributes.title, date: card.attributes.publishingDate, thumbnail: baseURL+card.attributes.thumbMedia.data.attributes.formats.thumbnail.url)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        self.selectedNew = card
                                        self.showFullNew = true
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                        .sheet(isPresented: $showFullNew, onDismiss: {
                            self.selectedNew = nil
                        }) {
                            if let selectedNew = selectedNew {
                                FullNewsView(title: selectedNew.attributes.title, date: selectedNew.attributes.publishingDate, thumbnail: baseURL+selectedNew.attributes.thumbMedia.data.attributes.formats.thumbnail.url)
                                    .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.98)])
                            }
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }.onAppear {
                        vm.fetchNewsFromAPI()
                    }
```

Comment: you could try using `.sheet(item: $selectedNew){ item in ... }`
 or capture the variable, such as
 `.sheet(isPresented: $showFullNew) { [selectedNew] in ...}`